# Contents of ScrollView leaking out of the parent view in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, android-scrollview

The layout file below should give you the idea that I want the contents of scroll view inside the RelativeLayout below the TextView, but the contents of the ScrollView go out of the RelativeLayout to get hidden behind the TextView. I don't understand how this is happening. In the RelativeLayout inside the ScrollView I'm adding a LinearLayoutCompat object programmatically and to that object I am adding several AppCompatTextView object also programmatically. The screenshot is just 1 instance of the layout.

I am setting the nested RelativeLayout to start below the TextView but still it starts from the very top.

**layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/narrowTextnon"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/cherryRed"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:padding="25dp"
        android:text="Let's narrow down now !"
        android:textColor="@color/wineBrown"
        android:textSize="22sp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/narrowTextnon"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/dataContnon"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center">

            </RelativeLayout>

        </ScrollView>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got what I wanted by applying :   
`android:layout_height="match_parent"` to nested RelativeLayout to position the ScrollView in center      
`android:layout_below="@id/narrowText"` to have the ScrollView start from below the TextView instead of the very top.   
`android:layout_alignParentBottom = true` to have the ScrollView stretch from the bottom of the TextView to the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Normal behaviour of RelativeLayout, what I would do is change root layout to RelativeLayout, and in nested RelativeLayout declare `android:layout_below="@id/narrowText"`

Comment: Well you mighht combine my answer wit @Robert K. answer and you will end up changing root layout to `RelativeLayout`, setting `android:layout_below="@id/narrowText"` and changing nested RelativeLayout height to wrap_content

Comment: I am going to go back a few steps but this time include both solutions of changing root layout to 'RelativeLayout'  as well as setting it to android:layout_below="@id/narrowText". I will keep one screen shot of what I have now.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your problem is in this line:
`android:layout_height="match_parent"` here: `<RelativeLayout                     //To position ScrollView in center`.

Try `wrap_content` there.

Comment: If I do that my ScrollContent contents are pushed towards the top. I want them centered